# Changing "and others" to "et al"

Tags: biblatex

I have a reference list that is more than 4 authors and I set the `maxcitenames=3,` and my footnote reference looks like this now:

> Alberto Garcia-Garcia andothers. Appl. Soft Comput. J., 70: 41–65, 2018.

However, i want to replace the "and others" to "et al".

I am currently using `biblatex` with the options below

```
\usepackage[hyperref=true,
            url=false,
            isbn=false,
            backref=false,
            style=custom-numeric-comp,
            citereset=chapter,
            maxcitenames=3,
            maxbibnames=100,
            uniquename=false, 
            uniquelist=false,
            backend=bibtex, % This option was needed to generate bibliography for new systems
            block=none]{biblatex}
```

How can I get "et al.", please?

[image]

```
%  \sjcitep (superscript citation number, short cite info in footnote).

    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
    \usepackage{charter} % optional: activate bitstream charter font
    \usepackage[hyperref=true,
                url=false,
                isbn=false,
                backref=true,
                style=custom-numeric-comp,
                citereset=chapter,
                maxcitenames=3,
                maxbibnames=100,
                backend=bibtex, % while checking on one of my (newest) systems, this option was needed to generate bibliography
                block=none]{biblatex}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    
    % back reference text preceding the page number ("see p.")
    \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
        backrefpage  = {see p.}, % for single page number
        backrefpages = {see pp.} % for multiple page numbers
    }
    
    % the followings activate 'custom-english-ordinal-sscript.lbx'
    % in order to print ordinal 'edition' suffixes as superscripts,
    % and adjusts (reduces) spacing between suffix and following "ed."
    \DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{custom-english-ordinal-sscript}
    \DeclareFieldFormat{edition}%
                       {\ifinteger{#1}%
                        {\mkbibordedition{#1}\addthinspace{}ed.}%
                        {#1\isdot}}
    
    % removes period at the very end of bibliographic record
    \renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}
    
    % removes period after DOI and suppresses capitalization
    % of the word following DOI ("See p. xx" -> "see p. xx")
    \renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addspace\midsentence}
    
    \DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibemph{#1},} % italic journal title with comma
    \DeclareFieldFormat[inbook,thesis]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}\addperiod} % italic title with period
    \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1} % title of journal article is printed as normal text
    \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\textbf{#1}\addcolon\space} % makes volume of journal bold and adds colon
    \DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1} % removes pagination (p./pp.) before page numbers
    
    %%%%%%%%%
    % the command \sjcitep defined below prints footnote citation above punctuation
    \newlength{\spc} % declare a variable to save spacing value
    \newcommand{\sjcitep}[2][]{% new command with two arguments: optional (#1) and mandatory (#2)
            \settowidth{\spc}{#1}% set value of \spc variable to the width of #1 argument
            \addtolength{\spc}{-1.8\spc}% subtract from \spc about two (1.8) of its values making its magnitude negative
            #1% print the optional argument
            \hspace*{\spc}% print an additional negative spacing stored in \spc after #1
            \supershortnotecite{#2}}% print (cite) the mandatory argument
    %%%%%%%%%
    
    \bibliography{example_ref_list}  % includes file "example_ref_list.bib" with data on the cited references
    
    
    \begin{document}
    
    This is an example of how to reference in LaTeX\sjcitep[.]{Garcia-Garcia2018}.
    
    % prints author names as small caps
    \renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
    \renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
    \renewcommand{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
    \renewcommand{\mkbibnameaffix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
    
    \printbibliography
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: What is your declared language?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the output? Does it really say `andothers` in one word without space? Is the `andothers` in bold? `biblatex` will print the name of the bibstrings (like `andothers`) in bold if they are not found in  the language you are loading. It is possible that you are loading a language that isn't supported by `biblatex` at all. But in order to investigate this properly we'd need to see an example document that reproduces the problematic output with as little (extra) code as possible (an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: Hi @Bernard. I am using English as the main language. I am writing my Thesis in English.

Comment: Hi @moewe. I am using customized 'Biblatex' I found here: [link](http://www.khirevich.com/latex/biblatex/). MWE:

Comment: @moewe I couldn't upload everything in the MWE, However, a mwe is found in this website [link](http://www.khirevich.com/latex/biblatex/) at the top. That is the one i am using as an example. It compiles fine for me. It is just that i get **andothers** instead of  _et al_

Comment: I don't understand. ‘*et al.’ is the default in english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following document reproduces the issue

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[maxcitenames=3,]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{custom-english-ordinal-sscript}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,aksin}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

when it is run with the `custom-english-ordinal-sscript.lbx` available from http://www.khirevich.com/latex/biblatex/ (http://www.khirevich.com/downloads/example_latex_bib_foot.rar). That `custom-english-ordinal-sscript.lbx` contains

```
\ProvidesFile{custom-english-ordinal-sscript.lbx}


% This file redefines '\mkbibordinal' command, and contains
% its standard definition (from english.lbx) with the only 
% difference in one line with '\mkbibsuperscript{...}'


\InheritBibliographyExtras{english}
\DeclareBibliographyExtras{%
  \protected\def\mkbibordinal#1{%
    \begingroup%
    \@tempcnta0#1\relax\number\@tempcnta%
    \@whilenum\@tempcnta>100\do{\advance\@tempcnta-100\relax}%
    \ifnum\@tempcnta>20%
      \@whilenum\@tempcnta>9\do{\advance\@tempcnta-10\relax}%
    \fi%
    \mkbibsuperscript{\ifcase\@tempcnta th\or st\or nd\or rd\else th\fi}%
    \endgroup}%
  \protected\def\mkbibmascord{\mkbibordinal}%
  \protected\def\mkbibfemord{\mkbibordinal}%
}

\endinput
```

This `.lbx` file is missing string declarations/inheritance rules. So it does not define any strings at all. Which means that you just get the bold names of the strings and a warning.

---

We can fix this by adding and inheritance rule for strings to the `.lbx` file

```
\InheritBibliographyStrings{english}
```

Then the file would read

```
\ProvidesFile{custom-english-ordinal-sscript.lbx}


% This file redefines '\mkbibordinal' command, and contains
% its standard definition (from english.lbx) with the only 
% difference in one line with '\mkbibsuperscript{...}'


\InheritBibliographyExtras{english}
\DeclareBibliographyExtras{%
  \protected\def\mkbibordinal#1{%
    \begingroup%
    \@tempcnta0#1\relax\number\@tempcnta%
    \@whilenum\@tempcnta>100\do{\advance\@tempcnta-100\relax}%
    \ifnum\@tempcnta>20%
      \@whilenum\@tempcnta>9\do{\advance\@tempcnta-10\relax}%
    \fi%
    \mkbibsuperscript{\ifcase\@tempcnta th\or st\or nd\or rd\else th\fi}%
    \endgroup}%
  \protected\def\mkbibmascord{\mkbibordinal}%
  \protected\def\mkbibfemord{\mkbibordinal}%
}

\InheritBibliographyStrings{english}

\endinput
```

---

Alternatively, since the `.lbx` file essentially just contains the redefinition of three macros, we can just get rid of it completely and do what the `.lbx` file does directly in the preamble. Remove the

```
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{custom-english-ordinal-sscript}
```

from your document and replace it with

```
\makeatletter
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibordinal#1{%
    \begingroup%
    \@tempcnta0#1\relax\number\@tempcnta%
    \@whilenum\@tempcnta>100\do{\advance\@tempcnta-100\relax}%
    \ifnum\@tempcnta>20%
      \@whilenum\@tempcnta>9\do{\advance\@tempcnta-10\relax}%
    \fi%
    \mkbibsuperscript{\ifcase\@tempcnta th\or st\or nd\or rd\else th\fi}%
    \endgroup}%
  \protected\def\mkbibmascord{\mkbibordinal}%
  \protected\def\mkbibfemord{\mkbibordinal}%
}
\makeatother
```

to obtain

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[maxcitenames=3,]{biblatex}
\makeatletter
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibordinal#1{%
    \begingroup%
    \@tempcnta0#1\relax\number\@tempcnta%
    \@whilenum\@tempcnta>100\do{\advance\@tempcnta-100\relax}%
    \ifnum\@tempcnta>20%
      \@whilenum\@tempcnta>9\do{\advance\@tempcnta-10\relax}%
    \fi%
    \mkbibsuperscript{\ifcase\@tempcnta th\or st\or nd\or rd\else th\fi}%
    \endgroup}%
  \protected\def\mkbibmascord{\mkbibordinal}%
  \protected\def\mkbibfemord{\mkbibordinal}%
}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,aksin}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. That worked. Cheers.